# How can I access secrets from Hashicorp Vault deployed on OpenShift/Kubernetes directly in my Python code?

Tags: python, kubernetes, openshift, hashicorp-vault

We can deploy a Hashicorp Vault on an OpenShift Cluster using Help (see [this](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-openshift?in=vault/kubernetes) and [this](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-access-encrypted-variables-on-openshift/)). Following the same links, this allows us to enable authentication by Kubernetes and to request secrets directly from Vault in these environments:

```
vault kv put foo/bar username="static-user" password="static-password"

vault kv get foo/bar
```

While this is ideal for an Openshift/Kubernetes environment, I would rather prefer to work with a Secret Manager client that I can access within my Python code as a library, for example something like this:

```
class SomeSecretManager():
    """Implementation of the contract of SecretManager"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None

    def initialize_connection(self):
        self.client = SecretsManagerV1(authenticator="how do I make this link with an OpenShift cluster")

    def get_secret(self, secret_id: str) -> Union[str, dict]:
        response = self.client.get_secret(id=secret_id)
        return response.get_result()["resources"][0]["secret_data"]["payload"]
```

I am wondering now how I can make this transition to access the deployed Vault pod on an OpenShift cluster directly in my Python code (both locally as well as when deployed on OpenShift), using a client similar to what has been illustrated above.

Comment: Have you already looked at HVAC (the Vault Python bindings)? I have definitely used it multiple times before for the functionality in your general code in the question.

Comment: Just tried and experimented with it, but unsure how to authenticate the client when vault is installed in a private VPC OpenShift Cluster. Any ideas?

Comment: This is the doc for auth via k8s engine as mentioned in the question: https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/auth_methods/kubernetes.html.

Comment: Yeah but whats unclear to me is that when you develop, you are not in the k8 cluster, where vault is deployed. So how do you then communicate with vault if this is blocked by the VPC?

Comment: If the Kubernetes API endpoint is inaccessible, then you cannot retrieve a JWT for a service account for use with the Kubernetes authentication engine. I am also unsure how you would connect to the Vault cluster either if it is inaccessible by the networking rules.

Comment: Start with a simple auth method, like [userpass](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/userpass). You will get a sense of Vault that will help you enable K8S auth later. If you don't go all the way with Kubernetes Auth, you can settle on middle ground : [Approle authentication](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle).